# Core Data vs. SQLite for offline persistence of an existing databased exposed via OData

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, odata

I am creating an app that requires "offline" persistence of it's data that is exposed via an  OData web service.  The OData service gives me access to all the tables of the underlying database, as well as all the relevent database fields such as ID's.

Additionally, I already have a SQLite database schema that I can use.

**My question, and to which I have flip-flopped on twice already, is whether it is better to store the web service data on the device via SQLite directly (using FMDB), or to leverage Core Data?**

If I use Core Data, then I lose the relational benefits of Primary and Foreign keys, but gain the benefit of automatically nested/populated NSManagedObjects. I'm not totally sure of how best to recreate the relational nature of my data objects.

If I use SQLite, I can just straight insert/update the results of the web service calls, and automatically get relationships from existing Foreign Key columns.  The downside is I probably need to manually encapsulate my results in POCO objects.

My gut right now is telling me SQLite, but it seems as though the community overwhelmingly points to Core Data in any/all cases. If Core Data, how do I best create and maintain object relationships (especially when they are 1->many)

This app will not go into the app store, if any Apple-happy aspects are of issue.

Comment: The best way to create object relationships in Core Data is to.....create object relationships in Core Data.  You can create one-to-one and one-to-many by just adding it in your managed object model.

Comment: @borrrden So my question then is, is there a simple way to populate those relationships after importing each table? Would I need a complicated 2-pass algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data models relationships directly. So in your schema you might say e.g. that object A has a relationship with object B and that the relationship is 'to many'. However the relationships work like normal object references — you need to link each instance of A to all relevant instances of B, you don't [easily, or usually] just say 'A relates to B through foreign key bID' and then have the relationship deal with itself.

If you have a SQL persistent store then the way that's implemented is that each object gets an implicit unique key for its table. Relationships are modelled as an extra column that holds the key or keys of every linked object in the foreign table.

Other things people tend not to like about Core Data:

- if you rely consistently on the implicit data fetches then you'll often get poor performance, so you often end up with explicit queries anyway in order to populate results you're probably about to look at in a single database trip;
- since SQLite is not thread safe and Core Data objects maintain a live connection to their stores, Core Data objects are not thread safe (though `objectID` references to them are and you can fetch similarly safe dictionaries instead of live objects if you prefer);
- even once you've otherwise solved the threading issue, saves in the background still block accesses in the foreground as per the SQLite thread safety comment.

Conversely:

- since iOS 5 you can use `NSIncrementalStore` so that you just run Core Data queries and your Core Data store is smart enough to go to the server if it needs to — the main body of your code has no idea of whether data is local or remote and doesn't need to repeat itself when declaring what it's going to look for;
- you get the live database connection for free, so your objects automatically update themselves if the persistent store changes;
- if you're looking mainly to do iPhone-style table views then the work is almost entirely done for you already, you pretty much just supply the query;
- Core Data has a sophisticated system of faulting that largely resolves memory footprint issues when dealing with large data sets.

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but good information. I had never really looked into Incremental Stores, they look interesting, but seem to be aimed at cacheing/performance and not really 100% offline mode.

I went the route of SQLite, since it would be quickest to implement IMO.